# How to design a spacecraft attitude control system?

Tags: design, attitude

I have knowledge about basic control systems, mathematical modelling and deriving state space and transfer functions. I'm a part of a team designing a small satellite. Control will be achieved using RCS thrusters and reaction wheels. How do I design an attitude control system for such a satellite? References to lectures and/or books would be helpful. 
To be more specific, I'd like to learn more about the mathematical and analytical part, where the controller algorithm is designed, analysed and tested.

Comment: How big is the satellite and what attitude sensors are being used? Also what attitude requirements do you have?

Comment: ...never mind attitude monitoring systems - to determine how to achieve given attitude, the satellite needs to know what attitude it has.

Comment: Please stop deleting same questions after they've been closed and then posting exact copies as new ones. Doing so will only result in same action taken again and the system banning you from asking any more questions due to consistent low quality posts. Instead, rather see [Ask] page and work with commenters on improving the question (use the [edit] link below it) so it can also be answered meaningfully and completely without having to take stabs in the dark. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at *Space Mission Analysis and Design* by Larson and Wertz, it's standard literature on systems engineering. Additionally *[Spacecraft Attitude Determination and Control](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=GtzzpUN8VEoC&printsec=frontcover&dq=inauthor:%22Computer%20Sciences%20Corporation.%20Attitude%20Systems%20Operation%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjqpP3lgZ_JAhUGmg4KHVLqAzAQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q&f=false)* by Wertz will give you more information on the design of an ACS.

Comment: The satellite is about 60x50x50 cm, the RCS thrusters are of 0.5 or 1 N and the reaction wheels produce a torque of 1 mN-m. The attitude determination is done by 8 sun sensors, a star tracker, and an imu ( imu6050 ).